# what is a mysql 'packet', anyway

Tags: mysql, mysql5

Mysql 5.1: if we want to use very large blobs, apparently we need very large packets, configured identically on both ends. How large can we go before something explodes?

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: It's not TCP or UDP packets.

Comment: Provide a link to the documentation that you're reading that leads you to believe this.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html Sounds close to what is being asked.

Answer (score 3):

> what is a mysql 'packet', anyway

That page you linked to describes exactly what a packet is. It is:

- A communication packet is a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server
- A single row that is sent to the client
- A binary log event sent from a master replication server to a slave.

So, if your packet size is set to 16Mb, then you won't be able to return a row larger than 16Mb in size. If you have the potential to be storing a 500Mb BLOB then you will need to increase your packet size to > 500Mb to accomodate this.

> How large can we go before something
>   explodes?

MySQL cannot return a single row larger than 1Gb, so I guess your maximum blob size is `1Gb - size of other fields in row`

Comment: Actually, that's a link provided by sysadmin1138, the OP added it in after the comment was left. Which, as you pointed out, answers the question.